# Flutter Camera plugin (auto zoom)

Tags: flutter, plugins, camera

first of all sorry my english

I'm developing a flutter application using the camera flutter plugin, after capturing the images I upload to amazon's S3
everything works fine, but users have begun to complain that the images taken on my app and the camera's native app look very different

in my app the image looks like I've been zoomed in by cropping the sides and top

in the native app the area that the camera captures is much larger

I would like my app to take photos like the native app (same area)

it is possible?

I already searched and found nothing related to it, I already changed the

ResolutionPreset.max

changed the size of my cameraPreview

unsuccessfully

Any help is welcome

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve by updating the plugin version
I was using the camera: ^ 0.5.6

now I'm with
camera: ^ 0.5.7 + 3